# How can i display Bin Location in SAP b1 Goods Receipt PO

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, sapb1

How can I display Bin location in Sap business one Goods Receipt PO and Production order using Print Layout Document Designer (PLD)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to get the desired results.

```
DECLARE @DocNum int;
SET @DocNum = 123999;
SELECT T1.ItemCode, T3.ItemName, T2.WhsName, T1.[Quantity], T4.[BinCode]

FROM OPDN T0
inner join PDN1 T1 on T1.DocEntry=T0.DocEntry
inner join OWHS T2 on T2.WhsCode=T1.WhsCode
INNER JOIN OITM T3 ON T3.[ItemCode] = T1.[ItemCode] 
INNER JOIN OBIN T4 ON T2.[DftBinAbs] = T4.[AbsEntry]

WHERE T0.[DocNum]=@DocNum
```

Above `Query` will result in as per my DB;
[image]

Comment: This query results in only the SystemBinLocations set for the warehouse. what should be used if I need the current stock's bin-locators?